# execute script on server by user action

Tags: php, mysql

I didn't really know how to describe my problem on the title so I did my best.

I have a function that reset my website. I also have a time stamp in which that function should execute. the time stamp is changing every reset so I need to find a way to activate that function on que.

My best soultion so far was to write `time_to_reset()` function and if it's true run the script, but the script is heavy and I'm afraid it won't be possible to run it on some random user (the reset is happening only once) computer. 
He could exit the website before the script executed completly.
Also, I affraid in some situations the script will execute twice or more due of a few users logging in togather. this is another problem I'll be happy to get help solve.

I'm sorry for my bad english, and for the none code question :) I hate it too...

I'll gladly explain again if you didn't understand me. Thank you!

`EDIT:`
I don't have to use the users, it was only an idea I had.
I have an Admin panel written in PHP code, in which you can edit the date of the time for reset. There is a way to change CJ dates with php code? or any other way to make the reset happen without using the users?

Answer (score 10):

Queueing actions to run with page loads is pretty easy. Just make a table that holds the action(script/function) and when it needs to be run. Then you can grab the next action and if it's time to execute, just delete the row, that way your script can run and no-one else will trigger the action. If you just have the one action, you can just have the table store only the time to run it at.

In response to your concern that the script is heavy, scripts that are run at set intervals are really what cron was invented for, and for heavier actions on a PHP site, it's really the best option. If you're using a VPS you already have cron, just SSH into your server and run `crontab -e` to edit your crontab file and put in something like:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

to run your script every 5 minutes. (Here's more cron examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/)

Alternatively, if you can't setup cron jobs on your server, you can make your reset action run on its own page and use a webcron service like http://www.mywebcron.com/ to call that page at set intervals.

Answer (score 9):

You already know what the problem is.

> He could exit the website before the script executed completely

Two solutions for this problem. Basically you don't want to depend on browser for execution.

- Use Cron Job
- `ignore_user_abort(true);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php. It is very commonly used for taking huge backups.

> Also, I affraid in some situations the script will execute twice or
>   more due of a few users logging in togather

Put some locking system i.e don't execute the script if its already running, decent way would be to create a database entry or just a file just after starting the script. So next time your function is executed you can check the `status` if its already running.

---

**Update** as per conversation in comments

You can [touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) the file say `script.lock` when the script is executed first time. And also before executing the script check if the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and check modified time with [stat](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php)

```
$stat = stat('script.lock'); 
$mtime = $stat['mtime'];
```

Allow the script to execute only if file is not present and certain time has passed.

Delete the file when execution is completed.

Comment: If 15-25 users online at the same time, and say happen and 5 of them is refreshing the page in a really short time, almost simultaneity, won't it execute more then once even if I'll use databse or file to try and prevent it?

Comment: yes. just use `touch` to create a file say `script.lock` and check if `file_exists` before running the scripts. Make sure you do have a permission to write. And yes also do your tests. :)

Comment: @OfirH Also for best results, you can check the modified time of the file which was touched. run the file if it has passed 5 min or whatever. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are determined to do this via a user visit then set up a database table that allows PHP code to attempt to lock a reset specific row. You can set it up that only one process can lock the row and only if the current time is past the next reset due date.

The lock is done after generating the entire user page AND setting the PHP code so that it does not terminate if the user leaves the page.

This will let you do a few things:

1. Have all page loads check to see if the one row reset record is claimable/has been claimed. If so, give a notice that the site will reset in however much time is remaining (the locking PHP should manage this delay period).
2. Disconnect the locking PHP so that it can continue to run. Make sure to set it's execute time high enough to allow it to complete the entire task.
3. As part of reset, or reboot, or whatever it is that has to happen, unset the reset lock and set the next reset due date in the future as appropriate.

This is not really something I would recommend but I'm willing to assume there are reasons I don't understand that would make this an appropriate way to go about resetting some aspects of your server.

Answer (score 1):

Soo i think ur main answer is already done. You simply say that your code is heavy and you have afraid of getting unneeded resets of the TimeStamp right?
Right. soo if that is your problem you can simply fixe him by hadding on the user that loggins a Cookie With the timestamp and the Id of the user Encrypted (I normaly encrypt the password and add the encrypted password on the cookie soo it gets impossible to the user to change the cookie Id and know the other user Encrypted password) but taht is not the case.

The real fix:
You just need to have a table on a database, and add the User Id and the Timestamp of that user soo when he loggins you can check the timestamp, if you want to Execute scripts on user Action if that is what you really need, you need to make 1 php file with the actions and a token on the GET example:

actions.php?token=231sfa231dasdasd&action=Username

Soo the page will get a blank page with the username only of the current user.
You can make this interactive by Adding some Javascript Code and make it refresh himself when it changes aswell.

Not sure if i helped you but if i do tell me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't think you understood me. The reset is for all of the webstie and It happens only once every 3 months. I need it to happen when certian tmestamp is passed. The website is active and could have 15-25 users online and I need it to happen only once... that's the problem.

Comment: soo then you just need a Cron task

Comment: But I need the dates to be changeable from my PHP admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Seems using CronJob is your best solution

Do new PHP page configure how to run the "reset" thing and what triggers it also you can use Mysql to save next runs queue and you can process resets per queue.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ignore_user_abort` in your script.

#### ignore_user_abort()

Sets whether a client disconnect should cause a script to be aborted.

When running PHP as a command line script, and the script's tty goes away without the script being terminated then the script will die the next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to TRUE

For a full description of this function I would like to refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)